# How do I reprogram my 2011 Buick Regal to add remote start?

Tags: remote-start

Fairly common question all over the internet, people are asking how it's done. The story goes, this latest rendition of the Regal started off being manufactured in Germany. Since remote car starters are allegedly illegal in Europe, the Regal came with no remote start capability for a while.

However, we know the [capability exists](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_TdZMERm7w). I contacted this dealership recently since it was their own *hacking*, for lack of a better term, but they no longer do it. Don't know if GM called and told them to stop since they were [broadcasting it on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jk8HUx6UVLs&NR=1), or what the situation was. From that poster's YouTube vids I see he does BCM reprogramming for various GM vehicles, but doesn't respond to requests about the process or anything similar, either it's behind NDA or he doesn't play well with others.

Anyway, the dealership only charged ~$250 for this, so I doubt they ordered a completely different BCM, however I could be wrong. I say this because they also gave new keys (LaCrosse keys but the point being they had the remote start button on them for a true factory feel), and keys themselves aren't cheap. Tack on a BCM and there's really no profit to be made from my perspective.

I'm no n00b to programming, I've even worked on programming logic for a BCM, but as of now I can't find documentation on the 'net, even though I'll keep looking. If one could point me in the right direction that'd be great.

**Update**

It looks like I *might* need one of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0029XK9E8) to reprogram the BCM, but I'm not even sure if that's what needs to be done. Not to mention a quick google reveals those don't go for under $1K USD, and that's a little out of range for a remote starter project, factory retrofit or otherwise.

**Update2**

I stand corrected on the [lowest MDI price](http://store.dhgate.com/product/gm-mdi-scanner-multiple-diagnostic-interface/159270463.html/?utm_source=pla&utm_medium=GMC&utm_campaign=cndiag001&utm_term=159270463&f=bm%7c159270463%7c112010-VehicleTools%7cGMC%7cAdwords%7cpla%7ccndiag001%7cUS%7c112010002-DiagnosticTools%7cc%7c%7c%7c&gclid=CJ-HpKrp0bwCFQsSMwod7w4A1g), however, I wonder what the catch is.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Comment: @handsomez I installed an aftermarket one, I'll post an answer when I get more time. But, the short of it is it can be done with the factory fob if all you want is remote start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so in a nutshell, at this point I went aftermarket with a system from Avital.

Basically, I could have went remote start only and used the factory fob, but since I used the whole security system included I had to use an aftermarket one.

It connected to an intermediate module called a [DBALL2](http://www.xpresskit.com/VehicleCompatibility.aspx?p=undefined&year=2011&make=Buick&model=Regal&ps=1&s=0&c=0#). DBALL2 interfaces with the car's ignition disabling system and the Avital, to enable remote start.

Sorry I don't have awesome pictures at the moment, I might have a couple on my phone and if so I'll post at a later date.